# A count of JSON rows that have Objects, excluding rows that are null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using a **API** to generate the average time spent visiting a webpage and then dividing the sum of all returned values by the number of days set in the **API**.

```
let avgtime = 0;

for (i in data) {
  if (data[i].avg_time_on_site) {
    avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;
  }
}
$("#avgtime").html(avgtime / datePeriod);
```

Whereas `datePeriod` is the total amount of days returned by the API. For example, if the `datePeriod` is set to 30 it would return the last 30 days of `avgtime`.

The snippet of `avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;` returns all of `avg_time_on_site` from **JSON** as a sum and is divided by `datePeriod` to get the average over the set amount of days `$("#avgtime").html(avgtime / datePeriod);`.

My issue, however, is that this only works if a webpage has a return value for each and every day. If the webpage is not visited on a single day as shown in the example JSON below, `avgtime` will not be correct because it is dividing the sum of all return values by the total days, not the total amount of days that have rows.

```
{
   "2017-12-30":[],
   "2017-12-31":{
      "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
      "nb_visits":1,
      "avg_time_on_site":41,
   },
   "2018-01-01":{
      "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
      "nb_visits":2,
      "avg_time_on_site":52,
   },
   "2018-01-02":[],
   "2018-01-03":{
      "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
      "nb_visits":3,
      "avg_time_on_site":83,
   },
   "2018-01-04":[]
}
```

I would like to replace the function `datePeriod` from `$("#avgtime").html(avgtime / datePeriod);` with another that counts the total rows in **JSON**, excluding any days that do not have values.

I have tried researching the solution first but am at a loss. Thank you for your help.

**Here is my full script**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#DateSelector').val('30').trigger("change")
}, 1000);

function datePeriod() {
  let datePeriod = $("#DateSelector").val();
  $("#DateShow").html(datePeriod);
  $.getJSON(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last${datePeriod}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, (data) => {
    //console.log(data);
    let avgtime = 0;

    for (i in data) {
      if (data[i].avg_time_on_site) {
        avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;
      }
    }
    $("#avgtime").html(avgtime / datePeriod);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="datePeriod();">
   <option value="7">Last 7 Days</option>
   <option value="14">Last 14 Days</option>
   <option value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
   <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
   <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
</select>

<h2 id="avgtime"></h2>
```

Comment: Just keep your own count inside your `if` block. Init a second `var` to 0 before the loop, then increase by one whenever you add to `avgtime`.

Comment: @ChrisG. Sorry, I don't quite understand. Are you suggesting, I take `data[i].avg_time_on_site` and divide it by the `length` of  `avg_time_on_site`. So to count only the `avg_time_on_site`? I had tried to perform the sum inside of here but couldn't get a valid response.

Comment: The answer below shows what I meant.

Comment: Note that this is a **very** odd average.  This is the average average-time-on-site over that period.  Wouldn't you prefer either the average user's time on site or the average visit time on site for that period?  The latter might looks like `(0 + (1 * 41) + (2 * 52) + 0 + (3 * 83) + 0) / (0 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 3 + 0) => 249 / 6 ~> 185`

Comment: Or it looks like you could use `sum_visit_length` from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you just keep track of the days in your loop with another variable. That way you are independent on the `datePeriod`.

```
let avgtime = 0;
//another variable, because you can't use datePeriod
let dayCount = 0;

for (i in data) {
  if (data[i].avg_time_on_site) {
    avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;
    dayCount++;
  }
}
$("#avgtime").html(avgtime / dayCount);
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you and once able I will mark as the correct answer.

Comment: an addition of `hasOwnProperty` will improve it further.

Comment: I would agree, in addition it also completely eliminated the need for 'datePeriod' variable.

Comment: @AGoranov no datePeriod is used in his getJSON-Request

Comment: @Christian Ah, thank you for the correction. It still would be better not to be dependent on the value checked when calculating the average. This should solely be done inside the loop with an additional variable.

Comment: It works as I asked so thank you. Is there an easy way to round the number to no decimal? I think I am having troubles because it is `.html(sum)` ?

Comment: @Darren Just use the js Math object: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach.  Normalize the data using `map`, and then `reduce` it to an aggregate object before finally dividing the total time by the number of visits.

See my note on the question about the odd average being used.  Here I supply one that gives the average time spent per visit over the dates supplied.

```
const avg = visits => (({cnt, time}) => time / cnt)(Object.values(visits).map(
  // Normalize to [{cnt: 0, avg: 0}, {cnt: 1, avg: 41}, ...]
  day => ({cnt: day.nb_visits || 0, avg: day.avg_time_on_site || 0})
).reduce(
  // combine to {count: 6, time: 394}
  (totals, day) => ({cnt: totals.cnt + day.cnt, time: totals.time + day.cnt * day.avg}), 
  {cnt: 0, time: 0}
))

avg(visits) //=> 65.666666666667
```

This could be somewhat simplified by using `sum_visit_date` instead of `avg_time_on_site`: you could skip the multiplication.  But that's a minor change.